# Print bottom view of a binary tree

Tags: algorithms, binary-trees

For a binary tree we define horizontal distance as follows:

```
    Horizontal distance(hd) of root = 0
    If you go left then hd = hd(of its parent)-1, and 
    if you go right then hd = hd(of its parent)+1.
```

The bottom view of a tree then consists of all the nodes of the tree, where there is no node with the same `hd` and a greater level. (There may be multiple such nodes for a given value of `hd`. In this case all of them belong to the bottom view.) I'm looking for an algorithm that outputs the bottom view of a tree.

---

Examples:

Suppose the binary tree is:

```
         1
        /  \
       2    3
      / \  / \
     4   5 6  7
            \
             8
```

Bottom view of the tree is: 4 2 5 6 8 7

```
    Ok so for the first example,
    Horizontal distance of node with value 1: 0, level = 1
    Horizontal distance of node with value 2: 0 - 1 = -1, level = 2
    Horizontal distance of node with value 3: 0 + 1 = 1, level = 2
    Horizontal distance of node with value 4: -1 - 1 = -2, level = 3
    Horizontal distance of node with value 5: -1 + 1 = 0, level = 3
    Horizontal distance of node with value 6: 1 - 1 = 0, level = 3
    Horizontal distance of node with value 7: 1 + 1 = 2, level = 3
    Horizontal distance of node with value 8: 0 + 1 = 1, level = 4

    So for each vertical line that is for hd=0, print those nodes which appear in the last level of that line.
    So for hd = -2, print 4
    for hd = -1, print 2
    for hd = 0, print 5 and 6 because they both appear in the last level of that vertical line
    for hd = 1, print 8
    for hd = 2, print 7
```

One more example for reference :

```
         1
      /     \
    2         3
   / \       / \
  4   5     6     7 
 / \ / \   / \    / \
8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

So the output for this will be :
8 4 9 10 12 5 6 11 13 14 7 15

```
Similarly for this example
hd of node with value 1: 0, , level = 1
hd of node with value 2: -1, level = 2
hd of node with value 3: 1, level = 2
hd of node with value 4: -2, level = 3
hd of node with value 5: 0, , level = 3
hd of node with value 6: 0, level = 3
hd of node with value 7: 2, level = 3
hd of node with value 8: -3, level = 4
hd of node with value 9: -1, level = 4
hd of node with value 10: -1, level = 4
hd of node with value 11: 1, level = 4
hd of node with value 12: -1, level = 4
hd of node with value 13: 1, level = 4
hd of node with value 14: 1, level = 4
hd of node with value 15: 3, level = 4

So, the output will be:
hd = -3, print 8
hd = -2, print 4
hd = -1, print 9 10 12
hd = 0, print 5 6
hd = 1, print 11 13 14
hd = 2, print 7
hd = 3, print 15 

So the ouput will be:
8 4 9 10 12 5 6 11 13 14 7 15
```

---

I already know a method in which I can do it using a lot of extra space (a map, and a 1-D array for storing the level of the last element in that vertical line) and with time complexity of $O(N \log N)$.
And this is the implementation of this method:

```
void printBottom(Node *node, int level, int hd, int min, map< int, vector<int> >& visited, int lev[], int l)
{
     if(node == NULL)
             return;
     if(level == 1){
              if(lev[hd-min] == 0 || lev[hd-min] == l){
                      lev[hd-min] = l;
                      visited[hd-min].push_back(node->data);
              }
     }
     else if(level > 1)
     {
          printBottom(node->left, level-1, hd-1, min, visited, lev, l);
          printBottom(node->right, level-1, hd+1, min, visited, lev, l);
     }
}


int main()
{
    find the minimum and maximum values for hd via DFS

    int lev[max-min+1]; //lev[hd] contains the maximum level for which we have found nodes with this value of hd; initialized with 0's

    map < int, vector<int> > visited; //the nodes in the bottom view

    int h = height(root);

    for (int i=h; i>0; i--){
        printBottom(root, i, 0, min, visited, lev, i);
    }

    output visited
}
```

I am seeking help to do this in more optimized way, which used less space or time. Is there any other efficient method for this problem?

Comment: Please get rid of the source code and replace it with ideas, pseudo code and arguments of correctness. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/64/) and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/390/) for related meta discussions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you can get the time complexity down to ${\cal O}(n)$, while keeping the same space complexity. You can do this by filling `visited` in a single run of `printBottom`:

```
void printBottom(Node *node, int level, int hd, int min, map< int, vector<int> >& visited, int lev[])
{
     if(node == NULL)
             return;
     if(lev[hd-min] < level){
         lev[hd-min] = level;
         visited[hd-min] = new vector<int>; //erase old values, they are hidden by the current node
     }
     if(lev[hd-min] <= level){
         visited[hd-min].push_back(node->data);
     }
     printBottom(node->left, level+1, hd-1, min, visited, lev);
     printBottom(node->right, level+1, hd+1, min, visited, lev);
}
```

with the initial call `printBottom(root, 1, 0, min, visited, lev);`

If you insist on the nodes beig output in order of increasing value of `hd`, I don't think you can improve space consumption. However, if you allow a different order of output, you can get rid of `visited`, by first determining for each value of 'hd', which level should be output and then making another pass, printing the values that match:

```
void fillLev(Node *node, int level, int hd, int min, int lev[])
{
     if(node == NULL)
             return;
     if(lev[hd-min] < level){
         lev[hd-min] = level;
     }
     fillLev(node->left, level+1, hd-1, min, lev);
     fillLev(node->right, level+1, hd+1, min, lev);
}
void printBottom(Node *node, int level, int hd, int min, int lev[])
{
     if(node == NULL)
             return;
     if(lev[hd-min] == level){
         cout << node->data;
     }
     printBottom(node->left, level+1, hd-1, min, lev);
     printBottom(node->right, level+1, hd+1, min, lev);
}
```

with calls `fillLev(root, 1, 0, min, lev);` and `printBottom(root, 1, 0, min, lev);`.